# Mysql - detect transaction that inserts data

Tags: mysql, triggers, transactions, mysql-5.1

I'm trying to identify which transaction inserts data into a db table into a **Mysql 5.1** server using **innodb** engine. Unfortunately I don't have access at the source code and thus I have to try to guess what's happening by looking at data on the DB.

It seems to me that a Dataset that is supposed to be written into the db in a single transaction is instead written into 2 separate transactions. I would like to test if this assumption is true or not.

In order to do that, my idea was to add a column into my table, let's say TransactionID, and than with a trigger copy the transactionId value on that column.

But I've found that seems not possible to detect in mysql 5.1 the TransactionId for innodb engine.

Do you know whether there's other options to identify the transaction involved into data insertion?

Comment: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html

Comment: Thank you @Drew, unfortunately I'm sticked to mysql 5.1 I'll modify the question to make it more evident.

Comment: It is a modern reference that has implications with prior releases. Also if you don't have any source code, frankly what is the point?

Comment: This link says, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/sql-syntax.html#create-trigger

Comment: Trigger is just the only way i guess.

Comment: @Drew I just want to verify my assumption..

Comment: @reds maybe using a timestamp inside the trigger should give the same values for all the rows inside the same transaction..

Comment: It is impossible i guess coz trigger fired every transaction.. On the other hand timestamp become a unique if you use this as a reference by using now(). im just hoping this is what you mean.

Comment: @reds you are right.. I was thinking possible to create and value a 'global' timestamp variable before the the loop on inserted rows and thus using the same value for all the rows inside the loop

Comment: If you use variable as timestamp value, technically it could be the same if you are going to put it or insert it to any table. It depends on you